# is there any other sql clause like where?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status, 
    tbl_employee.emp_id, 
    tbl_employee.emp_lname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_mname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_fname 
FROM tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN tbl_employee 
    ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.in_out >= '2015-05-01' 
    AND tbl_tmpdtr.in_out <= '2015-05-05'
GROUP BY
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid
```

In the SQL query above, I would like to query using a specific `id`. But I already used the `WHERE` clause. How can I properly do this? Or do you guys have any idea how? Or any method?

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: If I understood your question, use `AND` as may as you want. `WHERE` isnot something which you use it one per query.

Comment: mysql @wewesthemenace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your condition using `AND` clause in either `ON` **or** `WHERE` clause.

**ON**:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status, 
    tbl_employee.emp_id, 
    tbl_employee.emp_lname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_mname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_fname 
FROM tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN tbl_employee 
    ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
      AND tbl_tmpdtr.id = {some id}
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.in_out >= '2015-05-01' 
    AND tbl_tmpdtr.in_out <= '2015-05-05'
GROUP BY
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid
```

**WHERE**:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status, 
    tbl_employee.emp_id, 
    tbl_employee.emp_lname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_mname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_fname 
FROM tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN tbl_employee 
    ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.in_out >= '2015-05-01' 
    AND tbl_tmpdtr.in_out <= '2015-05-05'
    AND tbl_tmpdtr.id = {some id}
GROUP BY
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this will help you:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status, 
    tbl_employee.emp_id, 
    tbl_employee.emp_lname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_mname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_fname 
FROM tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN tbl_employee 
    ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.in_out >= '2015-05-01' 
    AND tbl_tmpdtr.in_out <= '2015-05-05' and tbl_tmpdtr.id=(specific id)
GROUP BY
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status, 
    tbl_employee.emp_id, 
    tbl_employee.emp_lname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_mname, 
    tbl_employee.emp_fname 
FROM tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN tbl_employee 
    ON tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.in_out between '2015-05-01' and  '2015-05-05' and tbl_tmpdtr.id=(specific id)
GROUP BY
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid
```